# How to load Interstitial ad after x actions

Tags: java, android, admob

I am editing the code of an existing android application (not a game). I want to show an interstitial ad after a certain number of screens or actions taken (Respecting Google guidance).

This is how I normally load my interstitial ad:

```
// Prepare the Interstitial Ad
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(News_Detail.this);

// Insert the Ad Unit ID
interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

// Load ads into Interstitial Ads
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

// Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener

interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Call displayInterstitial() function
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });
```

```
  public void displayInterstitial() {
    // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.

 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Your code to show add
            if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                interstitial.show();
            }
        }
    }, 20000);
    }
```

Comment: I have a quiz app. If I show an interstitial ad after every X questions (e.g. 15 questions) is this acceptable to Google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep track of actions using an `int`, make a method that increments it, and checks if you should show an ad. If yes, show an ad and reset it.

```
private static int x = 0;

public static void incrementActions() {
    x++;
    if(x >= 5) {
        x = 0;
        displayInterstital();
    }
}
```

Put it in your MainActivity for example, and call it like this: `MainActivity.incrementActions()`.
Also make your `displayInterstital()` method static, or give the method an Object of the class it is in.

Comment: Thanks , but the variable x it wont change his value , if i put this function like that !

Comment: x++ is the same as x = x + 1

Comment: yes it increment it , and where do i have to put this code ?